DataGrid slots prop
I need to add an accordion in the datagrid using slots. I have a datagrid, which is listing the data correctly. I am looking for some way to add an accordion in the row, so that the row opens when clicked and accordion data can be visible for the selected row.
I am trying to achieve this using slots.
I am aware that by using slots.row I can override the row, however I cannot find any documentation or examples which showcase how I can properly add an accordion to the row.
<DataGrid
columns={columns}
rows={tableRows}
slots={{
   row: (data) => {
        return
         Hello;
        }
     }}/>

